# Using location hash to pass parameters between javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

Let's suppose we have a simple function that calls another function passing a parameter:

```
let funcA = () => {
    let parameter;
    ....
    funcB(parameter)
}

let funcB = (parameter) => {
    ...
}
```

Would it be considered a bad practice to implement same logic passing the parameter through a url hash, using the triggered `.onhashchange` event?

```
let funcA = () => {
    let parameter;
    ...
    window.location.hash = parameter;
}

let funcB = (parameter) => {
    ...
}

window.onhashchange = () => {funcB(window.location.hash.substring(1))}
```

Schematically, the 2 approaches are as following:

> **function A** --(parameter)--> **function B**

> **function A** --(parameter)--> **hash** --(parameter)--> **function B**

Of course, in general, the 1st option is cleaner, straight-forward and there is no need to pass the variable through a 3rd "service" (the url hash).

However, I am working on a web app that already implements a "hash logic" and actually, using the 2nd option may result in a cleaner code that is easier to understand and maintain.

Are there **any disadvantages on the 2nd approach** (for example, worse performance)?

Comment: Just as a second set of eyes here -- I am highly skeptical of the claim that the 2nd option could ever be "easier to understand."

Also the onhashchange function as written above won't work; you'd need something like window.onhashchange = function(e) { funcB(window.location.hash.substring(1) }

Comment: For the 2nd part of your comment, you are right, I edited the code. As for the 1st part, the web app is already reading hash variables when loading and refreshes them while user interacts. Thinking of this specific app as an exception, I think that the described hash logic would be cleaner, indeed. The hash would act as a service for multiple functions to communicate, using the "onhashchange" event.